# replace text in specific field with variables from loop

Tags: awk, sed, search

I have a huge file to parse & need to search and replace text but in specific fields, sharing a small sample for reference named dest. first row is header for reference.

```
cat dest
ID|NAME|COMPANY|NUMBER
1001|Adam||15001
1002|eve|adam&eve|15002
1003|||
1004|||50000
1005|||50001
```

I have separate files that contain pattern to match, text-to-be-replaced & text-to-replace

```
cat src
1003||15003
1004|50000|15004
1005|50001|15005
```

so I can run a given below while loop with sed to achieve for last 2 rows from src file.

```
cat src | while IFS=$'|'; read id old new; do sed -i "/^${id}/s/${old}/${new}/" dest; done
```

but for `ID=1003` I get empty string for `$old`, and it will replace all empty columns in dest file for that ID. Which I want to avoid. What I want to do is replace only last field.

DESIRED:

```
ID|NAME|COMPANY|NUMBER
1001|Adam||15001
1002|eve|adam&eve|15002
1003|||15003
1004|||15004
1005|||15005
```

I could go with awk as it is more granular, when comes to columnar data. but awk will print out multiple times to stdout, as much as I understand, which is not practical either in my case.

so is there a way that I can do it in smart & concise way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
 NR==FNR  { id[$1, $2]=$3; next }
          { $4=( ($1, $4) in id? id[$1, $4]: $4) } 1' src dest
```

- FS: **F**ield **S**eperator
- OFS: **O**utput **F**ield **S**eperator
- NR==FNR: An always true condition idiom for the first input file.

  NR is present the total **N**umber of **R**ecords that awk read;
  FNR is present each individual **F**ile's **N**umber of **R**ecords.
- `id[$1, $2]=$3`: An associated awk array.

  Name: id
  key: column#1+column#2
  value: column#3

  first block only runs for the first input file, i. e, file *src*.

In this `$4=($1, $4) in id? id[$1, $4]: $4`, we are updating the value of the last column (`$NF` or `$4` ) of the second file, i. e, file *dest* from the matched keys combination of the column#1+column#4 in *id* array, if found then return that value (`id[$1, $4]`), otherwise copy its current value.

Comment: a little explanation would be needed, as I have to map field numbers in actual file, which may have more fields at hand.

Comment: can we use column numbers instead of $NF? cause it still confuses me, besides I have to use column numbers because my fields are different than $NF for actual data

Comment: @Sollosa no problem, see the edit. now that  in awk if you count columnsfrom the left2right, it's `$1`, `$2`, `$3`,... and if you count from the right2left, it's  `$NF` (last column), `$(NF-1)` (2nd to last column), `$(NF-2)` (3rd to last column), ...; Additionally, `$0` is always represent the entire record as well

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` solution, which assumes that the lines from `src` will be used exactly once each and in order.  This allows us to only keep track of the next line from `src` until it has been used, and then read the next one in.

```bash
awk -F '|' '
    BEGIN { OFS=FS }
    ! have {
        getline line <"src"
        split(line, pat)
        have = 1
    }
    $1 == pat[1] {
        if ($4 == pat[2]) $4 = pat[3]
        have = 0
    }; 1' dest
```

If the flag `have` is not set, or zero, the next line from `src` is read into `line` and split up into the array `pat`.  This is done in the `! have` block.

If the current line of input from `dest` has a 1st field that is identical to the first element of `pat`, then we'll test the 4th field against `pat[2]` and replace it with `pat[3]` if they are the same.  The `have` flag is then reset to zero to trigger reading a new line in from `src`.

The trailing `1` at the end of the `awk` program causes the (possibly modified) record to be outputted.

The output, given the data in the question:

```
ID|NAME|COMPANY|NUMBER
1001|Adam||15001
1002|eve|adam&eve|15002
1003|||15003
1004|||15004
1005|||15005
```