# awk get column value from file 2 for file 1 if value matches in 2 columns

Tags: awk, search, replace

I have 2 files, trying to set column value that is taken from file2 into file1 when their columns match

```
file1:
signup||20200620|A3332|en|LA||ACTIVE
signup||20200620|B4443|en|CA|66001|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|C2221|en|WC||ACTIVE
signup||20200620|D1110|en|LA||ACTIVE
signup||20200620|E5554|en|WC|66003|ACTIVE
```

---

```
file2:
A3332||99001
B4443|66001|99003
D1110|66004|99007
E5554||99004
```

---

**CRITERIA:**
$4 of file1 must match $1 of file2, after matching it should set $7 of file1 equal to $3 of file2

---

DESIRED:

```
signup||20200620|A3332|en|LA|99001|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|B4443|en|CA|99003|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|C2221|en|WC||ACTIVE
signup||20200620|D1110|en|LA|99007|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|E5554|en|WC|99004|ACTIVE
```

---

what I'm trying

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" } NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1; b[NR]=$3; next} {if (a[FNR] = $4); $7=b[FNR]; print}' file2 file1
```

---

What I'm getting

```
signup||20200620|A3332|en|LA|99001|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|B4443|en|CA|99003|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|C2221|en|WC|99007|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|D1110|en|LA|99004|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|E5554|en|WC||ACTIVE
```

I'm scratching head if it's a logical error or something else

Comment: This is the same problem as [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/707263/133219) but the attempt you show isn't [the answer you accepted to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707269/133219) which is... odd. It's discouraging to see you not learning from and using the answers you get.

Comment: in your previous question, you stated that _"I have separate files that contain pattern to match, text-to-be-replaced & text-to-replace"_, so I choice the key/value mapping as the combination of the "pattern to match, text-to-be-replaced" (col#1+col#2 in `id[$1, $2]`) and value from "text-to-replace" (`$3` in the `id[$1, $2]=$3`). but here in your file2 (called src in the previous question) has a record such as `D1110|66004|99007` which there is no matched record in file1 (called dest in the previous question) with "pattern to match, text-to-be-replaced" (col#7 in file1 is empty)  ..........

Comment: ............ but in the desired output I see you replaced it (in `signup||20200620|D1110|en|LA|99007|ACTIVE`) based on just matched id regardless of the "text-to-be-replaced" if it's there or not, so here you should build your array as just `id[$1]=$3` from the file2 and use `$7=( $4 in id? id[$4]: $7)` for the file1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems. First, you have a typo:

```
if (a[FNR] = $4)
```

That will always be true since you're using `=`, the assignment operator instead of `==` for comparison. You need:

```
if (a[FNR] == $4)
```

The next problem is that you don't have the same number of lines in your file. So even if you fix the typo, it won't work as expected:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" } NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1; b[NR]=$3; next} {if (a[FNR] == $4){$7=b[FNR]}; print}' file2 file1
signup||20200620|A3332|en|LA|99001|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|B4443|en|CA|99003|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|C2221|en|WC||ACTIVE
signup||20200620|D1110|en|LA||ACTIVE
signup||20200620|E5554|en|WC|66003|ACTIVE
```

The `D1110` line isn't working because `D1110` is on line 4 in `file` but line 3 in `file2`. So you need a different approach, something like this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" } NR==FNR{a[$1]=$3; next} {if ($4 in a){$7=a[$4]}; print}' file2 file1
signup||20200620|A3332|en|LA|99001|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|B4443|en|CA|99003|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|C2221|en|WC||ACTIVE
signup||20200620|D1110|en|LA|99007|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|E5554|en|WC|99004|ACTIVE
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps formatting the script will help the logic:

```
awk -F\| '
NR == FNR       {A[$1] = $3; next}
($4 in A)       {$7 = A[$4]}
1' file2 OFS=\| file1

signup||20200620|A3332|en|LA|99001|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|B4443|en|CA|99003|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|C2221|en|WC||ACTIVE
signup||20200620|D1110|en|LA|99007|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|E5554|en|WC|99004|ACTIVE
```

If you still need to match on the second field, then you can combine the fields:

```
awk -F\| '
NR == FNR       {A[$1,$2] = $3; next}
($4,$7) in A    {$7 = A[$4,$7]}
1' file2 OFS=\| file1

signup||20200620|A3332|en|LA|99001|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|B4443|en|CA|99003|ACTIVE
signup||20200620|C2221|en|WC||ACTIVE
signup||20200620|D1110|en|LA||ACTIVE
signup||20200620|E5554|en|WC|66003|ACTIVE
```